# Nested dictionary creation with setdefault

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash-map

Is there a better way of creating a nested dictionary than what I'm doing below? The result for the `setdefault` is because I don't know whether that particular key exists yet or not.

```
def record_execution_log_action(
        execution_log, region, service, resource, resource_id, resource_action
    ):
        execution_log["AWS"].setdefault(region, {}).setdefault(service, {}).setdefault(
            resource, []
        ).append(
            {
                "id": resource_id,
                "action": resource_action,
                "timestamp": datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
            }
        )
```

Comment: You can used a `defaultdict` from `collections` module instead, it automatically creates the default( this can be a `list`) if the `key` is not found.

Comment: I've created about `defaultdict` but I don't get how to use it for my nested use case properly. Could you give an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `defaultdict` like so:

```
from collections import defaultdict

resource_dict = lambda: defaultdict(list)
service_dict = lambda: defaultdict(resource_dict)
region_dict = lambda: defaultdict(service_dict)
execution_log = defaultdict(region_dict)

execution_log['AWS']['region']['service']['resource'].append({
                "id": 'resource_id',
                "action": 'resource_action',
                "timestamp": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
            })

execution_log
```

output:

```
defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>()>,
            {'AWS': defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>()>,
                         {'region': defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>()>,
                                      {'service': defaultdict(list,
                                                   {'resource': [{'id': 'resource_id',
                                                      'action': 'resource_action',
                                                      'timestamp': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'}]})})})})
```